# Aligning text differently when columns are stacked vs side by side

Tags: css

I am trying to create a page layout with a header that needs to include 2 pieces of in information (which I have placed in two divs). On wider screens, I want to align one block to the left, and one to the right, but on smaller screens, I want to stack both blocks, and center all of the text.

So far, however, I have been unable to accomplish both of these goals. Is this even possible without resorting to JavaScript?

Here is the HTML I have so far:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        Text on the left
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        Text on the right
    </div>
```

And the CSS:

```css
.container {
        padding: 0px;
    }
    .left {
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .right {
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

I know that the `float: left` and `float: right` are what prevents the text from centering when stacked, but I don't know how else to make sure that the `left` and `right` blocks end up in the corners when they are *not* stacked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a media query to change the css at smaller screen widths. Ie, you could just change the .right div to float left instead at smaller screens widths:

```
@media (max-width: 600px){
    .right{
        float:left;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a little hard to give a concrete answer as the question doesn't demonstrate the actual desired layout but is more general in its requirements. With that said, here's what I suggest.

I would set a width on your `.left` and `.right` DIVs along with using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to adjust for stacking behavior. I have two examples below.

### 1)

In this example both `.left` and `.right` are set to `width: 50%`. You could change it up to 40%/60% or whatever. The main takeaway here is they're both floated to the left so the widths will have to equal 100%;

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        Text on the left.
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        Text on the right.
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
    text-align: center;
}    
@media (min-width: 400px) {
    .left,
    .right {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/00ap8rnn/

### 2)

```css
.container {
    text-align: center;
}
@media (min-width: 400px) {
    .left {
        float: left;
        width: 30%;
    }
    .right {
        float: right;
        width: 15%;
    }
}
```

In this example both DIV widths do not have to equal 100% and one is floated to the right and the other floated to the left.

jsFiddel: http://jsfiddle.net/00ap8rnn/1/